# (ANDROID) ImageView won't position correctly

Tags: android, imageview

I have an Android related issue:
I am trying to centre a logo on the screen of my device, but it won't position correctly.
I am using the following function:

```
public void ImageCentered(int ID){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(ID);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    x = (screenWidth/2)-(iv.getWidth()/2);
    y = (screenHeight/2)-(iv.getHeight()/2);
    position.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

    iv.setLayoutParams(position);
}
```

This could should work,but it won't. The image is set off slightly to the right and bottom like in this image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf7r1u1xqcmb9t9/2014-08-16%2018.36.04.png

Now, the strange thing is, when I use the following code:

```
public void ImageCentered(int ID){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(ID);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    x = (screenWidth/2)-(iv.getWidth()/2);
    y = (screenHeight/2)-(iv.getHeight()/2);
    position.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
    Message(IntToStr(x)+", "+IntToStr(y));

    iv.setLayoutParams(position);
}
```

this is the result:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mjw80zlzkav6dzs/2014-08-16%2018.41.16.png

*Side note: The text in the **Message()** function does not matter, nor does its position within the **ImageCentered()** function.*

I am not calling the function in my OnCreate(), as the width and height of the image would always return 0, so I looked something up and found this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){     
    ImageCentered(R.id.image);
}
```

This piece of code is in my **MainActivity.java** file, whereas the **ImageCentered()** function is in my **UtilLib.java** file.

So, I was wondering: What's going on here? Why does the code work when I pop in a **Message()** but not when I leave it out?
Sure, I can try hardcoding the data, but what about smaller/bigger screens?

I hope an Android guru can help me out here, as I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.

**EDIT**
Just noticed something interesting when pressing "OK" on my Message:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7lu6588hy1opw7/2014-08-16%2018.51.55.png

My guess is that my problem lies there, but after clicking the "OK" button once more, the data is "492, 207" again. *scratches head*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ultimately decided to just hardcode the **x and y** coordinates, and later on use some sort of scaling-conversion to position them properly, unless someone can provide me with a better method of fixing this.

**UPDATE**
So, after googling after a while (again), I have finally found the answer and created two functions:

```
public int GetImageHeight(int ID){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(ID);
    iv.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    iv.layout(0, 0, iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight());

    return iv.getMeasuredHeight();
}
public int GetImageWidth(int ID){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(ID);
    iv.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
               MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    iv.layout(0, 0, iv.getMeasuredWidth(), iv.getMeasuredHeight());

    return iv.getMeasuredWidth();
}
```

All you have to do is pass the ID of the image you made in your xml file, like so:

```
GetImageHeight(R.id.logo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rom your code that the ImageView is inside a RelativeLayout, You could also do:

```
// get imageview layout params or create new ones
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

this way the image will be automatically centered without all those manual calculations!.

You can also specify it in the XML with

```
 <ImageView .....
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: That would be an even better solution purely for centered images. My app (game), however, will require the width and height from such calculations I posted.

Comment: uh ok I thought something else was going on, too much calcs for just centering an image & forgetting about it!